# XML to List<T>using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is a snippet of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
-<e80:td941 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.xxx.html e80_td941.xsd 
https://www.xxx.html e80_reports_common_structs.xsd 
https://www.xxx.html e80_reports_data_types.xsd" 
xmlns:e80="https://www.xxx.html">
-<e80:rptHd>
<e80:exchNam>X</e80:exchNam>
<e80:envText>P</e80:envText>
<e80:rptCod>td941</e80:rptCod>
<e80:rptNam>Daily performance</e80:rptNam>
<e80:rptPrntEffDat>2013-08-09</e80:rptPrntEffDat>
<e80:rptPrntRunDat>2013-08-10</e80:rptPrntRunDat>
</e80:rptHd>
-<e80:td941Grp>
  -<e80:td941KeyGrp>
     <e80:membExchIdCod>xx999</e80:membExchIdCod>
     <e80:membExchIdNam>xx997ed</e80:membExchIdNam>
  </e80:td941KeyGrp>
 -<e80:td941Rec>
    <e80:prodId>5AB</e80:prodId>
    <e80:quoReqTot>0</e80:quoReqTot>
    <e80:dCutLim>150</e80:dCutLim>
    <e80:goodQuoReqResp>0</e80:goodQuoReqResp>
    <e80:quoReqViol>0</e80:quoReqViol>
    <e80:shtQuoPct>0.00</e80:shtQuoPct>
    <e80:valQuoReqViol>0</e80:valQuoReqViol>
    <e80:valQuoReqTot>0</e80:valQuoReqTot>
    <e80:valGoodQuoReqResp>0</e80:valGoodQuoReqResp>
    <e80:violPct>0.00</e80:violPct>
</e80:td941Rec>
.
.
.
</e80:td941Grp>
</e80:td941>
```

as can be seen here the aim of the code is to get those elements under  into a class object, so I have done this so far,

```
public class td941Rec
{


    private string _prodID;
    private string _qouReqTot;
    private string _dCutLim;
    private string _goodQuoRepResp;
    private string _quoReqViol;
    private string _shtQuoPct;
    private string _valQuoReqViol;
    private string _ValQuoRepTot;
    private string _valGoodQuoReqResp;
    private string _violPct;


    public string prodID { get { return _prodID; } set { _prodID = value; } }
    public string qouReqTot { get { return _qouReqTot; } set { _qouReqTot = value; } }
    public string dCutLim { get { return _dCutLim; } set { _dCutLim = value; } }
    public string goodQuoRepResp { get { return _goodQuoRepResp; } set {
                                                         _goodQuoRepResp = value; } }
    public string quoReqViol {get {return _quoReqViol; } set { _quoReqViol = value; } }
    public string shtQuoPct { get { return _shtQuoPct; } set { _shtQuoPct = value; } }
    public string valQuoReqViol {get{return _valQuoReqViol; } set {_valQuoReqViol 
                                                                    = value;}}
    public string ValQuoRepTot { get { return _ValQuoRepTot; } set { _ValQuoRepTot 
                                                                         = value; } }
    public string valGoodQuoReqResp { get { return _valGoodQuoReqResp; } set { 
                                                     _valGoodQuoReqResp = value; } }
    public string violPct { get { return _violPct; } set { _violPct = value; } }

}

public class td941Grp
{
    private string _td941;
    public string td941 { get { return _td941; } set { _td941 = value; } }

    public List<td941Rec> dataList = new List<td941Rec>();
}


class QoutePerformance
{


    public void xmltoExcel()
    {
        string xmlDoc = @"C:......xml";

        XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(xmlDoc);
        XNamespace ns = "e80";
        td941Grp objtd941 = new td941Grp();

        List<td941Grp> listtd941 = (from _td941 in xdoc1.Element(ns +
                                               "td941").Elements(ns + "td941Grp")
                          select new td941Grp
                          {
                          td941 = _td941.Element(ns + "td941Grp").Value,
                          dataList = (from _record in _td941.Element(ns +
                                       "td941Grp").Elements(ns + "td941Rec")
                          select new td941Rec
                          {
                           prodID = _td941.Element(ns + "prodID").Value,
                           qouReqTot = _td941.Element(ns + "qouReqTot").Value,
                           dCutLim = _td941.Element(ns + "dCutlim").Value,
                           goodQuoRepResp = _td941.Element(ns + "goodQuoRepResp").Value


                                                 }).ToList()


                                 }).ToList();



    }
```

(please excuse the formmating of the code)

I have read lots of pages and tried to make sense of it. But cannot seem to get it to work.
The code above return a nullException object reference not set to an instance of an object (but I have a feeling even if that is solved, its not going to work. would someone be so kind as to show me how I would get the xml into a list?

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: At which line the exception was thrown?

Comment: List<td941Grp> listtd941.................... the last block of code

Comment: I warned you under your prev question: include the full stacktrace. We want to know which line threw which error.

Comment: You should also *massively* reduce the amount of code you post. A short but complete program (with real XML rather than the version you've given here with all those `-` signs) would be much, much clearer. You could demonstrate the problem with about 5 lines of XML and 10 lines of C#, if that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman how do i do that, pardon my ignorance but im a newb... using visual studio 10

Comment: One thing I usually do in scenarios like this is to create instances with dummy data, then serialize it to an XML file. I then compare the outputted file with the existing file, that will help determine what .NET is expecting vs what it is getting.

Comment: When you have the exception in the debugger you can View Details and copy the relevant data to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem (or at least *a* problem):

```
XNamespace ns = "e80";
```

You're specifying the *alias*, which isn't really the namespace. You want:

```
XNamespace ns = "https://www.xxx.html";
```

As specified here in the XML:

```
xmlns:e80="https://www.xxx.html"
```

Because you're specifying the wrong namespace, your `Element` call is returning `null`, which you're then dereferencing.

Comment: ok so changed that, ran the code.. it returns back from the class td941Grp taking public List<td941Rec> dataList.... and then throws the exception again.... i apologise if i have used a lot of code, im a bit lost..

Comment: @Timujin - yes, what happend to `xmlDoc.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("e80");` ?

Comment: @Timujin: This is the problem with having so much code already - it makes it hard to find one problem at a time. My guess is that you've got the exception at a different line now. Use this information so far to create a *new* question which shows a *short but complete* program demonstrating the problem - assuming you still have one. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Thanks. I will read through the website. Line 53 is where it throws the exceptopn, select new td941GRp

Comment: @Timujin: You're currently looking for a `td941Grp` element *within* a `td941Grp` element. That doesn't exist. Again, you *really* need to simplify things. Take everything one step at a time. Your query is much too large to just pick off errors one by one like this, especially if you're new. Take baby steps.